# Display text from QLineEdit in a QTextEdit already containing some text and update it in real time

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qlineedit

What is the procedure to make a text being written in a `QLineEdit` widget, dynamically display inside a `QTextEdit` that already contains some text?

For example, let us say that a `QLineEdit` asks for a name where one writes "John". Is it possible to display it in real time inside a `QTextEdit` containing :

*The name is* + `textFromQLineEdit` + *, age 24* ?

The displayed text has to dynamically take into account the changes being made to the `QLineEdit` so that the user does not need to press a button or press enter to see his/her name appear.

The following is the minimal code for connecting the two widgets to each other using the signal `textChanged()` from `QLineEdit` and the slot `setText()` from `QTextEdit` (which does not allow for adding some text *before and after* the text from the `QLineEdit`) :

```
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QApplication>

class SmallWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SmallWindow();
private:
    QLineEdit *nameLine;
    QTextEdit *textBox;
};

SmallWindow::SmallWindow() : QWidget()
{
    setFixedSize(300,250);
    QLineEdit *nameLine = new QLineEdit;
    QTextEdit *textBox = new QTextEdit;
    QWidget::connect(nameLine,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),textBox,SLOT(setText(QString)));
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(nameLine);
    layout->addWidget(textBox);
    QGroupBox *group = new QGroupBox(this);
    group->setLayout(layout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    SmallWindow window;
    window.show();
    app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

What should be done to keep the text before and after the `QLineEdit` text in place and updating the `QTextEdit` box in real time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create special slot:

```
void SmallWindow::pasteText(const QString& str)
{
    textBox->setText(QString("The name is %1 , age 24").arg(str)); 
}
```

and don't use `textChanged()` signal because you need only one name accepted by user, so you need `QLineEdit::editingFinished()` (or maybe `QLineEdit::returnPressed()`, it depends on your needs)

```
connect(nameLine,SIGNAL(editingFinished(QString)),this,SLOT(pasteText(QString)));
```

Also you don't need `QWidget::connect`, because you write this code inside `QObject` subclass, so it is not necessary.

Also these lines:

```
QLineEdit *nameLine = new QLineEdit;
QTextEdit *textBox = new QTextEdit;
```

should be:

```
nameLine = new QLineEdit;
textBox = new QTextEdit;
```

Comment: First: thanks for all your tips! Second: I tried your code, but in my computer I had to replace `textBox` by `this` in the `connect` command in order to make it work... Any ideas why?

Comment: @jrojasqu Oh, yes, sorry, it was my typo (I copy-pasted your code and forgot change all things) Yes, you need `this`, because you try to use SmallWindow's slot, not a QTextEdit(QTextEdit has no pasteText slot at all).

Answer (score 3):

Create an own slot for the text update. I think that you have also some errors in your code.

Widgets nameLine and textBox are already defined in the SmallWindow.h. You probably want to create them in SmallWindow.cpp following way:

```
nameLine = new QLineEdit;
textBox = new QTextEdit;
```

Also GroupBox group is not set to any layouts. Perhaps you want to create one layout more and set the widget there?

```
QVBoxLayout *mainlayout = new QVBoxLayout;
mainlayout->addWidget(group);   
this->setLayout(mainlayout);
```

If you create an own slot for the text update, you can just change text content of the textBox there:

**SmallWindow.h**

```
#ifndef SMALLWINDOW_H
#define SMALLWINDOW_H
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QTextEdit>
class SmallWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SmallWindow();

private slots:
 void updateLineEditText(QString name);

private:
    QLineEdit *nameLine;
    QTextEdit *textBox;
};
#endif // SMALLWINDOW_H
```

**SmallWindow.cpp**

```
#include "SmallWindow.h"
SmallWindow::SmallWindow() : QWidget()
{
    setFixedSize(300,250);
    nameLine = new QLineEdit;
    textBox = new QTextEdit;   
    connect(nameLine,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,
    SLOT(updateLineEditText(QString)));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(nameLine);
    layout->addWidget(textBox);
    QGroupBox *group = new QGroupBox(this);
    group->setLayout(layout);

    QVBoxLayout *mainlayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainlayout->addWidget(group);   
    this->setLayout(mainlayout);
}


void SmallWindow::updateLineEditText(QString name) {
    QString textEditString("The name is ");
    textEditString.append(name);
    textEditString.append(", age 24 ?");
    textBox->setText(textEditString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal example in Qt 5, using C++11. It is about as concise as it would be in Python. If you are using Qt 5, then your question should have looked exactly as it does below, save for the `connect` statement. This is what "minimal" means when it comes to Qt. Avoid the fluff and boilerplate that doesn't add to the problem. There's no need to have a separate class for the window in such a simple example.

```
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QWidget window;
   QVBoxLayout layout(&window);
   QLineEdit name;
   QTextEdit text;
   layout.addWidget(&name);
   layout.addWidget(&text);
   QObject::connect(&name, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&](const QString & name){
      text.setPlainText(QString("The name is %1, age 24.").arg(name));
   });
   window.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

The same in Qt 4 is below - note the absence of any manual memory management. That's how your question ideally should have looked for Qt 4, without the slot's implementation of course. You can use the `connectSlotsByName` or an explicit `connect`, of course - that's just a matter of style.

```
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QApplication>

class Window : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QVBoxLayout m_layout; // not a pointer!
   QLineEdit m_name; // not a pointer, must come after the layout!
   QTextEdit m_text;
   Q_SLOT void on_name_textChanged(const QString & name) {
      m_text.setPlainText(QString("The name is %1, age 24.").arg(name));
   }
public:
   Window() : m_layout(this) {
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_name);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_text);
      m_name.setObjectName("name");
      QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   Window window;
   window.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```